# Getting a syntax error i cannot fix

Tags: android

This is the line that causes the problem. kindly please help!

```
dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; 
                  name="uploaded_file";
                     "filename="""+ fileName + "" + lineEnd);
```

It returns error in uploaded_file and filename ")" and ";" and this "}"

kindly please tell what is wrong with this code ?

Comment: you need to give more details, copy entire class if needed

Comment: well one asked for proper line so I put the main code on it where the error was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax highlighting here on SO has highlighted the issue. You haven't properly escaped characters in the string:

```
dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploaded_file";"filename="""+ fileName + "" + lineEnd);
```

If you wish to insert a quote in the string and not actually close the string, you need to escape it with a back slash.

```
dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";\"filename=\"\""+ fileName + "" + lineEnd);
```

Comment: Thank you Scott Helme I will I could give your answer 2 points with a correct mark but I need 125 reputation points to do that. your answer is PERFECTO !

Comment: You should be able to mark this as the correct answer, no?

Comment: I did try to mark it but it returns and error with ( you need 15 reputation points to vote up ) xD

Comment: I green tick marked it. I got more error's in the next code will post now. need your help.

Comment: open up a new question then, but make sure, you can't find the answer easily in the internet or even in stackoverflow.com

Comment: @AndroidRookie You might also consider completing some basic programming tutorials and learn to use the debugger.  You will save everyone, including you, a lot of time.  This problem is very basic and very easy to solve with the debugger since you could look at the string being formed inside the brackets at runtime.

Comment: @Simon you probably meant "android" not me :D

Comment: yes I already know androidRookie. but the application doesn't run at debug time. because the android sdk gives the error that "please fix errors first then debug the application" . weird isn't it ? xD

Comment: anyway I am posting another question with full code in next thread.

Comment: I got a ban on my questions and I can't ask any further questions. omg. I need help to fix my errors!

Comment: But then you exactly know where the error ist, so no debugging is needed. You should see the error in your code, and the type of error. So just google for the error, and hopefully, you find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a backslash

```
dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";\"filename=\""+ fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
```

Comment: yes its good but in the last before the lineEnd between the quotation marks the backslash doesn't come because when I try to add backslash to it. It return the same error again, and also kindly please explain why use backslash ?

Comment: `backslash` represents that there is quotation mark as text not ending of string that you have started with `"Content-Disposition`

Answer (score 0):

```
dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";\"filename=\""+ fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
```

double qoutes are not used within double qoutes, you need to put "\" (backslash)

Comment: at the end of LineEnd before the filename "\"" + lineEnd); returns with serious error.